# Solr 3.6.1 replication master not found

Tags: solr, replication

Using Solr 3.6.1, I get the following error when executing the 'fetchindex' command on the slave at 10.0.0.73:

SEVERE: Master at: `http://10.0.0.249:8983/solr/my_core/replication` is not available. Index fetch failed. Exception: Request failed for the url org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod@388a2006

The my_core core on the master at 10.0.0.249 has the following config in solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >                    
    <lst name="master">                                                                  
        <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>                                          
        <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>                                         
        <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt</str>                            
    </lst>                                                                               
</requestHandler>
```

On the slave at 10.0.0.73 my_core has replication configured in its solrconfig.xml as

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">                   
  <lst name="slave">                                                                   
    <str name="masterUrl">http://10.0.0.249:8983/solr/my_core/replication</str>     
    <str name="pollInterval">00:00:60</str> 
  </lst>                                                                               
</requestHandler>
```

I guess I'm doing something obvious wrong, but can't find it after hours reading and re-reading the Solr documentation on replication and lots of posts here and on other sides. Anybody has an idea? Note that other requests sent to the master succeed, e.g.

```
GET http://10.0.0.249:8983/solr/my_core/select
```

returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                   
<response>                                                                               
  <lst name="responseHeader">
     <int name="status">0</int>
     <int name="QTime">0</int>
     <lst name="params"/>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
```

Comment: Check http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#enable.2Fdisable_master.2Fslave_in_a_node if you need to define the enable attribute to indicate it as a master and slave

Answer (score 1):

Your master URL on the slave configuration is specified as,

```
<str name="masterUrl">http://10.0.0.249:8983/solr/my_core/replication</str>
```

the correct url would be

```
<str name="masterUrl">http://10.0.0.249:8983/solr/my_core</str>
```

You need to specify the URL only till the core name.